# Find folders in a directory that has contains the folder name as US- and IS- vba

Tags: vba, vbscript, directory, fetch, names

From couple of days I have been searching for a vba or vbs code to list all folders that contains US- or IS- in a specific directory.
So far I have the below code which list all the documents but not the folder names.

```
    'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit
Sub Get_File_Name()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim SearchString As String
Dim TestPos As Integer

Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object
Dim i As Integer
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Working Documents\Client\OPTICS\")
i = 1
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "US-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "IS-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    'print folder name
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objSubFolder.Name
    'print folder path
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objSubFolder.Path
    i = i + 1
Else
End If
Next objSubFolder
End Sub
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use a simple [InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) inside the For Each loop to check if the filename contains US- or IS-:

```
If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "US-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "IS-", vbTextCompare) > 0
```

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for your help...I am not sure why the code is giving me run-time error.

Comment: What exactly is giving you which error? I copied your code and ran it without any problems

Comment: i = 1
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
If InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "US-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, objSubFolder.Name, "IS-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    'print folder name
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objSubFolder.Name
    'print folder path
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objSubFolder.Path
    i = i + 1
Else
End If

Comment: I think i am making some error...sorry i am just at first level. I copied you code and pasted it after the code {For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders} with if and endif.

Comment: And which error is it giving you? was your code working before?

Comment: It is not fetching the folder names...it is just picking all file names.

Comment: I have tried it out and it only shows me Folders, Files are ignored

Comment: I have edit the Original code above with the code and added the code which you gave me. Sorry to bug you with comments appreciate your help.

Comment: I still don't get why it is listing files for you, i copied your code 1:1 and it's only giving me Folders containing "US-" or "IS-"